Relating the eccentricities of the Gergonne-Steiner and Nine-point conics of a quadrilateral
Consider the following relation between a hyperbola and an ellipse:

$(1):$ the rectangles enclosed by the tangent lines passing through their vertices are similar and parallel.


My question is: How to prove

Given a convex quadrilateral, the Gergonne-Steiner Conic (the circumscribing conic of least eccentricity), and the Nine-point Conic (through the midpoints of the sides of the corresponding complete quadrangle) have relation $(1)$.


You can do experiment by moving quadrilateral $ABCD$ in GeoGebra share link, the orange ellipse is its Gergonne-Steiner Conic, the purple hyperbola is its Nine-point Conic. Two pairs of perpendicular dashed lines are their axes.

Related:

the eccentricity of the Gergonne-Steiner Conic is calculated in this post

formula of the eccentricity when the conic section is given in the general quadratic form


The statement $(1)$ has two parts ($\ldots$similar and parallel), the first part ($\ldots$similar) is equivalent to

$(2):$ the ratio of the shorter axis to the longer axis of them are equal.

Let eccentricities of the hyperbola and the ellipse be $e_1,e_2$. Then,

$\sqrt{e_1^2-1}$ is the ratio of minor and major axis of the hyperbola

$\sqrt{1-e_2^2}$ is the ratio of minor and major axis of the ellipse


Note that,

for a hyperbola, if $e_1<\sqrt2$ the major axis is longer than its minor axis, if $e_1>\sqrt2$ the minor axis is longer than its major axis.
for an ellipse, the major axis is always longer than its minor axis;

so $(2)$ is equivalent to,
$$\sqrt{1-e_2^2}=\cases{\sqrt{e_1^2-1}&if $e_1\le\sqrt2$\\
\dfrac1{\sqrt{e_1^2-1}}&if $e_1\ge\sqrt2$}\tag2
$$
or written as,
$$\tag2 \sqrt{1-e_2^2}=\min\left(\sqrt{e_1^2-1},\frac1{\sqrt{e_1^2-1}}\right)$$

Degenerate case of $(2)$, $e_1=\sqrt2,e_2=0$ corresponds to the following cases:
Case 1
When $A, B, C, D$ are concylic (the Gergonne-Steiner Conic becomes a circle), the Nine-point Conic becomes a Rectangular Hyperbola.
Case 2
When $A, B, C, D$ form an orthocentric system (the Nine-point Conic becomes a circle), the Gergonne-Steiner becomes a Rectangular Hyperbola. In fact, all conics passing through these four points are rectangular hyperbola by the Poncelet-Brianchon theorem.

$\newcommand{\sgn}{\operatorname{sgn}}$
Coordinatizing the vertices of $\square ABCD$ via
$$\begin{align}
A=\phantom{-}a(\cos\theta,\sin\theta) &\qquad B=\phantom{-}b(\cos(-\theta),\sin(-\theta)) \\
C=-c(\cos\theta,\sin\theta) &\qquad D=-d(\cos(-\theta),\sin(-\theta)) \\
\end{align}$$
the quadrilateral is convex when each of $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ is positive, degenerating to have collinear (or even coincident) vertices when $abcd=0$ or $\sin2\theta=0$; it may-or-may-not be convex for other signs. (If we know we have a convex quad, we can take all signs to be positive.) The quadrilateral is cyclic when $ac=bd$, as a consequence of the intersecting chords aspect of the Power-of-a-Point theorem applied to the origin.
One can show that the equation for the Gergonne-Steiner conic ("GS") is
$$\begin{align} 
0 &= x^2 \left((a c - b d)^2 + 8 a b c d \cos^2\theta \right) \sin^2\theta  \\
  &+ y^2\left((a c - b d)^2 + 8 a b c d \sin^2\theta \right)  \cos^2\theta  \\
  &- x y \left(a^2 c^2 - b^2 d^2 \right) \sin2\theta  \\
  &+x (a c + b d) (b c d - a b d + a c d - a b c) \sin2\theta\sin\theta \\
  &+y (a c + b d) (b c d - a b d - a c d + a b c) \sin2\theta\cos\theta \\
  &- a b c d (a c + b d) \sin^22\theta
\end{align} \tag1$$
and that of the Nine-point conic ("$9$pt") is
$$\begin{align}
0 &= 2 x^2 (a c - b d) \sin^2\theta \\
  &+ 2 y^2 (a c - b d) \cos^2\theta \\
  &- 2 x y (a c + b d) \sin2\theta \\
  &- \phantom{2}x (a b c - a b d - a c d + b c d) \sin2\theta\sin\theta \\
  &+ \phantom{2}y (a b c + a b d - a c d - b c d) \sin2\theta\cos\theta 
\end{align}\tag2$$
Writing $k_{ij}$ for the coefficient of $x^iy^j$ in a conic equation, one can calculate the expression $\Delta = k_{20}k_{02}-k_{11}^2$, which indicates the type of conic represented by the equation: ellipse, parabola, hyperbola for $\Delta > 0$, $\Delta =0$, $\Delta < 0$, respectively. For the conics in question, we have
$$\begin{align}
\text{$9$pt}:\quad\Delta_1 &= -a b c d \sin^22\theta \\
\text{GS}:\quad\Delta_2 &= 4 a b c d (a^2 c^2 + b^2 d^2 - 2 a b c d \cos4\theta) \sin^22\theta
\end{align} \tag3$$
For a degenerate quadrilateral, $\Delta_1=\Delta_2=0$, so the two conics are parabolas with eccentricities $e_1=e_2=1$ satisfying OP's relation $e_1^2+e_2^2=2$; we'll set this case aside for the remainder of the discussion. Otherwise, $\sgn(\Delta_1)=-\sgn(\Delta_2)$, so that one conic is an hyperbola and the other is an ellipse; in particular, $9$pt is an hyperbola while GS is an ellipse when $abcd>0$.
The eccentricity $e$ of a (non-parabola) conic satisfies
$$\frac{e^4}{1-e^2} = \frac{4 k_{11}^2 + (k_{20} - k_{02})^2}{k_{20} k_{02} - k_{11}^2} \tag4$$
Eccentricities $e_1$ and $e_2$ of $9$pt and GS satisfy
$$\begin{align}
\frac{e_1^4}{1-e_1^2} &= -\frac{a^2 c^2 + b^2 d^2 - 2 a b c d \cos4\theta}{a b c d\sin^22\theta}=-4-\frac{(ac-bd)^2}{abcd\sin^22\theta} \\[6pt]
\frac{e_2^4}{1-e_2^2} &= \frac{(a c - b d)^2}{a b c d \sin^22\theta}
\end{align}\tag5$$
Therefore,
$$0 = \frac{e_1^4}{1-e_1^2}+\frac{e_2^4}{1-e_2^2} +4 = 
-\frac{\left(e_1^2+e_2^2-2\right)\left(1 + \left(1 - e_1^2\right)\left(1-e_2^2\right)\right)}{\left(1-e_1^2\right) \left(1-e_2^2\right)} \tag6$$
whence
$$e_1^2+e_2^2=2 \qquad\text{or}\qquad \left(1-e_1^2\right)
\left(1-e_2^2\right)=-1 \tag7$$
Note that in either relation, if one eccentricity exceeds $1$, the other must fall short of $1$; hence, one conic is a hyperbola when the other is an ellipse. The first relation allows for both conics to be parabola.
To get at OP's relation, we'll write $h>1$ and $\ell<1$ for the "h"yperbolic and "ell"iptic eccentricities, so that $(7)$ is expressible thusly:
$$1-\ell^2\;=\;h^2-1 \qquad\text{or}\qquad 1-\ell^2\;=\;\frac{1}{h^2-1} \tag8$$
Since $0< 1-\ell^2\leq 1$ and since the mutually-reciprocal right-hand sides of the options in $(8)$ straddle $1$, we know that the valid option is the one with the smaller right-hand side, confirming OP's formulation (ignoring square roots)
$$1-\ell^2 \;=\; \min\left(h^2-1\;,\;\frac{1}{h^2-1}\right) \tag{$\star$}$$

Addendum. Addressing OP's request to show that the axes of the two conics are parallel ...
The angle of rotation $\phi$ of the axes of a conic satisfies this relation with the coefficients of the Cartesian equation:
$$\tan2\phi = \frac{2k_{11}}{k_{20}-k_{02}} \tag9$$
For both the Gergonne-Steiner and Nine-point conics parameterized as above, the right-hand side reduces to the same expression:
$$\frac{a c + b d}{a c - b d}\,\tan2\theta \tag{10}$$
which shows that the axes of the two conics are parallel.
Note. The case $ac=bd$ corresponds cyclic $\square ABCD$ whose circular Gergonne-Steiner conic has no preferred axes.

Although Blue already gave a very nice proof, I would like to share my approach with a different coordinatization. After deriving the equations of the two conics, I follow the final steps of Blue's proof above.
This proof uses Sympy intensively. The coordinatization is based on the following properties of a complete quadrangle.
(P1) There is a unique rectangular hyperbola through $A, B, C, D$, and the Euler-Poncelet point is the center of this hyperbola.
(P2) The Euler-Poncelet and Gergonne-Steiner point (the center of the Gergonne-Steiner conic) of $ABCD$ are symmetric through the centroid of $ABCD$. Each of these two points is the common point of four circles (see QA-P2, QA-P3 in the below link).
These properties can be found at QA-P2 - Euler-Poncelet point, QA-P3 - Gergonne-Steiner point, QA-Co2 and QA-Co3.
Because of (P1), I choose the coordinates such that
$$
   A = (a, 1/a), B = (b, 1/b), C = (c, 1/c), D = (d, 1/d)
$$
where $a, b, c, d$ are nonzero real numbers. The rectangular hyperbola that circumscribes the quadrangle has the equation $xy = 1$. The Euler-Poncelet point coincides with the origin, the centroid has coordinates $((a + b + c + d)/4, (1/a + 1/b + 1/c + 1/d)/4)$, and the Gergonne-Steiner point has coordinates $((a + b + c + d)/2, (1/a + 1/b + 1/c + 1/d)/2)$. From this, I derive the equations of the Gergonne-Steiner and the nine-point conic.
In the end, the equation of the Gergonne-Steiner conic is
$$
  x^{2} + abcd y^{2} - (a + b + c + d)x - abcd\left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} + \frac{1}{d}\right)y + (ab + ac + ad + bc + bd + cd) = 0
$$
and that of the nine-point conic is
$$
  x^{2} - abcd y^{2} - \frac{1}{2}(a + b + c + d)x + \frac{1}{2}abcd\left(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} + \frac{1}{d}\right)y = 0
$$
The following snippets show how to derive these equations with Sympy, which you can try on Google Colab. I derive the conic equation by the result that $(x_{i}, y_{i})$ where $i = 1,2,3,4,5,6$ lie on a conic if and only if
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & x_{1} & y_{1} & x_{1}^{2} & x_{1}y_{1} & y_{1}^{2} \\
1 & x_{2} & y_{2} & x_{2}^{2} & x_{2}y_{2} & y_{2}^{2} \\
1 & x_{3} & y_{3} & x_{3}^{2} & x_{3}y_{3} & y_{3}^{2} \\
1 & x_{4} & y_{4} & x_{4}^{2} & x_{4}y_{4} & y_{4}^{2} \\
1 & x_{5} & y_{5} & x_{5}^{2} & x_{5}y_{5} & y_{5}^{2} \\
1 & x_{6} & y_{6} & x_{6}^{2} & x_{6}y_{6} & y_{6}^{2}
\end{vmatrix} = 0
$$
# 1st cell - initialization
from sympy import *

x, y, a, b, c, d = symbols("x y a b c d")

# 2nd cell - the equation of the Gergonne-Steiner conic
expr = expand(det(Matrix([
    [1, x, y, x * y, x ** 2, y ** 2],
    [1, a, 1/a, 1, a ** 2, 1 / a ** 2],
    [1, b, 1/b, 1, b ** 2, 1 / b ** 2],
    [1, c, 1/c, 1, c ** 2, 1 / c ** 2],
    [1, d, 1/d, 1, d ** 2, 1 / d ** 2],
    [1, b + c + d, 1/b + 1/c + 1/d, (b + c + d) * (1 / b + 1 / c + 1 / d), (b + c + d) ** 2, (1/b + 1/c + 1/d) ** 2]
]))) * a ** 2 * b ** 3 * c ** 3 * d ** 3

# The conic passes through A, B, C, D and the reflection of A across the Gergonne-Steiner point

Then I get the coefficients
# 3rd cell - get the coefficients of the equation of the Gergonne-Steiner conic

p1 = Poly(expr, x, y)
print(factor(p1.coeff_monomial(x ** 2)))
print(factor(p1.coeff_monomial(y ** 2)))
print(factor(p1.coeff_monomial(x * y)))
print(factor(p1.coeff_monomial(x)))
print(factor(p1.coeff_monomial(y)))
print(factor(p1.coeff_monomial(1)))

# which give
# (a - b)*(a - c)*(a - d)*(b - c)*(b + c)*(b - d)*(b + d)*(c - d)*(c + d)
# a*b*c*d*(a - b)*(a - c)*(a - d)*(b - c)*(b + c)*(b - d)*(b + d)*(c - d)*(c + d)
# 0
# -(a - b)*(a - c)*(a - d)*(b - c)*(b + c)*(b - d)*(b + d)*(c - d)*(c + d)*(a + b + c + d)
# -(a - b)*(a - c)*(a - d)*(b - c)*(b + c)*(b - d)*(b + d)*(c - d)*(c + d)*(a*b*c + a*b*d + a*c*d + b*c*d)
# (a - b)*(a - c)*(a - d)*(b - c)*(b + c)*(b - d)*(b + d)*(c - d)*(c + d)*(a*b + a*c + a*d + b*c + b*d + c*d)

# they have a common factor: (a - b)*(a - c)*(a - d)*(b - c)*(b + c)*(b - d)*(b + d)*(c - d)*(c + d)

# 4th cell - the equation of the nine-point conic - it took me circa 10 minutes to finish this cell
m_ab_x = (a + b) / 2
m_ab_y = (a + b) / (2 * a * b)
m_bc_x = (b + c) / 2
m_bc_y = (b + c) / (2 * b * c)
m_ca_x = (c + a) / 2
m_ca_y = (c + a) / (2 * c * a)
m_da_x = (d + a) / 2
m_da_y = (d + a) / (2 * d * a)
m_db_x = (d + b) / 2
m_db_y = (d + b) / (2 * d * b)
m_dc_x = (d + c) / 2
m_dc_y = (d + c) / (2 * d * c)

expr2 = expand(det(Matrix([
    [1, x, y, x * y, x ** 2, y ** 2],
    [1, m_ab_x, m_ab_y, m_ab_x * m_ab_y, m_ab_x ** 2, m_ab_y ** 2],
    [1, m_bc_x, m_bc_y, m_bc_x * m_bc_y, m_bc_x ** 2, m_bc_y ** 2],
    [1, m_da_x, m_da_y, m_da_x * m_da_y, m_da_x ** 2, m_da_y ** 2],
    [1, m_db_x, m_db_y, m_db_x * m_db_y, m_db_x ** 2, m_db_y ** 2],
    [1, m_dc_x, m_dc_y, m_dc_x * m_dc_y, m_dc_x ** 2, m_dc_y ** 2]
]))) * 128 * a ** 3 * b ** 3 * c ** 3 * d ** 3

# 5th cell - get the coefficients of the equation of the nine-point conic
p2 = Poly(expr2, x, y)

print(factor(p2.coeff_monomial(x ** 2)))
print(factor(p2.coeff_monomial(y ** 2)))
print(factor(p2.coeff_monomial(x * y)))
print(factor(p2.coeff_monomial(x)))
print(factor(p2.coeff_monomial(y)))
print(factor(p2.coeff_monomial(1)))

# which give
# 2*(a - b)*(a - c)**2*(a - d)*(b - c)*(b - d)**2*(c - d)*(a*c - b*d)
# -2*a*b*c*d*(a - b)*(a - c)**2*(a - d)*(b - c)*(b - d)**2*(c - d)*(a*c - b*d)
# 0
# -(a - b)*(a - c)**2*(a - d)*(b - c)*(b - d)**2*(c - d)*(a*c - b*d)*(a + b + c + d)
# (a - b)*(a - c)**2*(a - d)*(b - c)*(b - d)**2*(c - d)*(a*c - b*d)*(a*b*c + a*b*d + a*c*d + b*c*d)
# 0
# they have a common factor - (a - b)*(a - c)**2*(a - d)*(b - c)*(b - d)**2*(c - d)*(a*c - b*d)

From the two equations, we can derive the eccentricities using the formula given in Ayoub B. Ayoub, The Eccentricity of a Conic Section, The College Mathematics Journal, Vol. 34, No. 2 (Mar., 2003), pp. 116-121. The eccentricity of the conic given by equation $p_{xx}x^{2} + p_{yy}y^{2} + p + 2p_{xy}xy + 2p_{x}x + 2p_{y}y = 0$ is
$$
e = \sqrt{\frac{2\sqrt{{(p_{xx} - p_{yy})}^{2} + 4p_{xy}^{2}}}{\mu (p_{xx} + p_{yy}) + \sqrt{{(p_{xx} - p_{yy})}^{2} + 4p_{xy}^{2}}}}
$$
where
$$
\mu = \operatorname{sign}\begin{vmatrix}
p_{xx} & p_{xy} & p_{x} \\
p_{xy} & p_{yy} & p_{y} \\
p_{x}  & p_{y}  & p
\end{vmatrix}.
$$
However, this formula is cumbersome because of $\mu$.
One way to bypass $\mu$ is to follow the final steps in Blue's proof. The equality
$$
\frac{e^{4}}{1 - e^{2}} = \frac{{(p_{xx} - p_{yy})}^{2} + 4p_{xy}^{2}}{p_{xx}p_{yy} - p_{xy}^{2}}
$$
is a corollary of the eccentricity formula.

Addition to @Blue's proof:
From @Blue's proof, the quadratic part of the equation of 2 conics $(1)$ and $(2)$ correspond to 2 matrixes
$$M_1=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 \left(8 a b c d \cos ^2(\theta )+(a c-b d)^2\right) \sin ^2(\theta ) & -\left(a^2 c^2-b^2 d^2\right)\sin (2 \theta ) \\
-\left(a^2 c^2-b^2 d^2\right) \sin (2 \theta ) & 2 \left(8 a b c d \sin ^2(\theta )+(a c-b d)^2\right) \cos ^2(\theta ) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
and
$$M_2=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 (a c-b d) \sin ^2(\theta ) & - (a c+b d)\sin (2 \theta ) \\
 -(a c+b d)\sin (2 \theta )  & 2 (a c-b d) \cos ^2(\theta ) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
They are related by
$$S\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 -k & 0 \\
 0 & k \\
\end{array}
\right)S^{-1}M_2=M_1$$
where $S=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\cos (2 \theta ) (a c-b d)+k & \cos (2 \theta ) (a c-b d)-k \\
 \sin (2 \theta ) (a c+b d) & \sin (2 \theta ) (a c+b d) \\
\end{array}
\right)$,
$k=\sqrt{(ac-bd)^2+4a b c d \sin (2 \theta )^2}$.
The eigenvectors of $M_1,M_2$ are parallel, so the axes of 2 conics are parallel.
The first eigenvalues of $M_1$ is $-k$ times the first eigenvalue of $M_2$, the second eigenvalues of $M_1$ is $k$ times the second eigenvalue of $M_2$.
